# Using navigation.toggleDrawer(), animation timing causes drawer to appear non-responsive

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

In react-native app for ios and android. I am using createDrawerNavigator as a child navigator to a create stack navigator for the application.

The navigator has a default, custom header that utilizes the onPress event of the component to call navigator.toggleDrawer()

navigation.toggleDrawer() works as expected when opening and closing the left hand drawer however, the issue comes into play when the user will click on the custom toggle button too fast. if taking, i click on the button, drawer opens. I Wait a full second then click on the button again and the drawer closes consistently.

the drawer animation only takes about 400ms to complete. So a user tries to click on the toggle button too quickly and the app seems unresponsive. the onPress event fires every time the toggle button is pressed

looking onto the state of the components. when toggled there is a key value pair of isDrawerIdle:true that becomes false during animation. even though visibly the drawer will complete the animation in ~ 400ms it will take a full second from the time navigation.toggle is called to the time isDrawerIdle is set back to true.

the issue is more pronounced on ios than in android but exists in both.

1. I would expect that the animation cancel and reverse or in the very least complete and reverse
2. I would not expect such a long duration after the visible animation to complete for the state to change and toggle be enabled

I have tracked state of the component but have hit a wall with this.

RN- 59.10
React-native-paper - 2.15.2
react-navigation 3.11.0

```
import { Appbar } from 'react-native-paper';
const router = createStackNavigator(
 {
  screenA:{
    screen: ClassA,
    navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
      header: (<Appbar.Header><Appbar.BackAction onPress={()=> navigation.pop()}/><Appbar.Header>)
    })
  },
  screenB:{
    screenB: ClassB,
    navigationOptions: [...similar to screenA]
  }
 },
 Main: { 
  screen: Main,
  navigationOptions:({navigation, screenProps}) => ({
    ...getActiveChildNavigationOptions(navigation, screenProps)
  })
},
{
 defaultNavigationOptions:({navigation} => {
  const subtitle= navigation.getParam('subtitle',null)
  return {
    header: (props) => {
     return (<Appbar.Header><Appbar.Action /*...*/ onPress={navigation.toggleDrawer} /></Appbar.Header>)
    }
  }
 })
}

)
```

Main.js

```
const Main = createDrawerNavigator({
   screenC:{screen:ClassC},
   screenD:{screen:ClassD}
}, {contentComponent: CustomDrawer})
```

no error message pop up. what i expect is for the animation of the left drawer to close and at the time it closes, to have the navigation respond to an open request. remove the 200-500ms delay before the drawer animation is active again.